# What image format supports transparency in Android?

Tags: android, graphics, transparency

I want to show an apple on screen but the image has a white background and it doesn't blend with the background of a tree.

Is there any image format in which only the red apple is displayed?

Answer (score 4):

**.png images** wont show the transparent area. But you will have to make sure that the "white" area is transparent and not white.

If its not a **.png** image just go in to photoshop or any other image editor, cut out (magic wand) the white area and save it as a **.png**